# Delphi (Indy) Server Freezing on Write

Tags: delphi, client-server, indy

I currently have stable code between a client (IdTCPClient) and a server (IdTCPServer) working all as planned. When I call the following function from an OnClick event of a button, however, the server freezes.

```
var
  SendStream: TMemoryStream;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  List: TList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  try
    //Load
    FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Path, fmOpenRead);
    FileStream.Position := 0;
    //Place into stream
    SendStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    SendStream.Write(Header, SizeOf(Header)); //This works; supporting code ommitted  for brevity
    SendStream.CopyFrom(FileStream, FileStream.Size);
    SendStream.Position := 0;

    TIdContext(fTCP.Contexts.LockList[0]).Connection.IOHandler.Write(SendStream, 0, True);
    fTCp.Contexts.LockList;
   if Assigned(Self.fServerOnSync) then Self.fServerOnSync(SizeOf(Header)) //event handler for main form

  finally
    FileStream.Free;
    SendStream.Free;
  end;
```

I am guessing it has something to do with deadlocking threads but for the life of me I have no idea why it's occuring.

Also, if I encapsulate the above code in some class that contains the IdTCP server, which will call my custom fServerOnSync event, is this threadsafe?

Cheers,
Adrian

Comment: Q: what exactly is "Self.fServerOnSync()"?

Comment: type TServerOnSync = procedure(HeaderSize: Integer) of Object;

Sorry; all of this is wrapped in a class with IdTCPServer as a field. Thus, when I instantiate this class, I set this event.

Comment: Even commenting out that line still causes the write freeze :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `fTCp.Contexts.LockList()` twice, but you are not calling `fTCp.Contexts.UnlockList()` at all, so the server will become deadlocked whenever it tries to access the `Contexts` list.  You need to unlock the list after you have locked it, eg:

```
var 
  SendStream: TMemoryStream; 
  FileStream: TFileStream; 
  List: TList; 
  I: Integer; 
begin 
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Path, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite); 
  try 
    SendStream := TMemoryStream.Create; 
    try
      SendStream.Write(Header, SizeOf(Header));
      SendStream.CopyFrom(FileStream, FileStream.Size); 
      SendStream.Position := 0; 

      List := fTCP.Contexts.LockList; 
      try
        TIdContext(List[0]).Connection.IOHandler.Write(SendStream, 0, True); 
      finally
        fTCP.Contexts.UnlockList; 
      end;
      if Assigned(fServerOnSync) then fServerOnSync(SizeOf(Header)); 
    finally 
      SendStream.Free; 
    end; 
  finally
    FileStream.Free; 
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid mistake, but still no luck; still freezes. :/ Does the client need to respond to this in order for it to work? Atm the client side is NOT programmed.

Comment: Indy uses blocking sockets, so if the client is not reading inbound data on its end, eventually the socket's internal send buffer will fill up and the socket will become blocked on the server side waiting for the client to empty the buffer. The only way to avoid a deadlock in that scenario would be to set a socket-level send timeout using the socket API directly. Indy does not implement send timeouts in its logic.