# How can I avoid freezing on Write to socket in Indy if the other end is not reading data from the Socket

Tags: delphi, indy, winsock2

I have a application with client and server sockets using Indy, compiled with Delphi 10.2.

The application have a working thread that processes requests from the different ports and write responses within the same thread using a call to something like this:

```
procedure TMyCommManager.WriteResponse(AHandler: TIdIOHandler; SomeData: SomeType);
var 
  idBytes: TidBytes;
  PacketSize: Integer;
begin
  SomeData.GetBytes(idBytes, PacketSize);
  AHandler.Write(DataBuffer, PacketSize);
end;
```

Almost all the time everything is working as expected, but we noticed the worker thread is freezing from time to time in production. After various iterations, we finally got to the point that all this is occurring in the call to the `TidIOHandler.Write()` and I'm quite sure it is happening because the other end for a single port is not reading the responses from the socket.

After a reset to the port from within the other end the worker thread *unfreezes* and keeps working as expected.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11625644/255257) from Remy Lebeau to the question [Delphi (Indy) Server Freezing on Write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11624937/255257), where he mentions in comments (emphasis mine):

> Indy uses blocking sockets, so if **the client is not reading inbound data on its end**, eventually the socket's internal send buffer will fill up and the socket will become blocked on the server side waiting for the client to empty the buffer. **The only way to avoid a deadlock in that scenario would be to set a socket-level send timeout using the socket API directly**. Indy does not implement send timeouts in its logic.

I'm looking for the correct way to set that timeout, via INDY or via a direct API call in Windows, but I'm stuck in that, so I come here looking for help.

If that's not possible, I could implement a Timeout mechanism on a secondary thread, but I'm not sure what's the correct way to *reset* the connection from this secondary thread on my end to let the worker thread continue it's work.

Comment: Isn't the correct solution to make sure that the other end of the socket reads?

Comment: @David, of course, but we are not in control of all the other ends. In the end, I'm trying to make our software as robust and stable as it could be and let the others take care of it's own applications.

Comment: I could re-engineer our application to have a dedicated thread to write to each of the connected ports, but it would require a considerable effort from my part, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: If you did that you'd end up with a thread that was blocked. Wouldn't that leave you in just as bad a position as you are now?

Comment: David, the application, for now have a limited number of working threads that are processing requests for many connections each. I think the writer thread is better in the way that all the connections can continue to get requests processed and responses, and the only freezed thread will be the one writing to that specific connection. That connection will eventually die or got reset on the other end, so the thread will become responsive again. Now all the connections bound to a thread are being unattended when that thread freezes. Changing that design is not possible for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm looking for the correct way to set that timeout, via INDY or via a direct API call in Windows

In my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624937/11625644#comment15412376_11625644), when I said "set a socket-level send timeout using the socket API directly", I was refering to the `SO_SNDTIMEO` socket option via the [`setsockopt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt) function.

In terms of Indy, you can call `setsockopt()` by using the `TIdSocketHandle.SetSockOpt()` method, eg:

```
// Windows

SomeConnection.Socket.Binding.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDTIMEO, TimeoutInMS);
```

```
// 'Nix

var tv: timeval;
...
SomeConnection.Socket.Binding.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDTIMEO, Integer(@timeval));

or:

GBSDStack.SetSocketOption(SomeConnection.Socket.Binding.Handle, Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDTIMEO, timeval, sizeof(timeval));
```

(the `TIdTCPConnection.Socket` property is a shorthand for accessing `TIdIOHandlerSocket` when the `TIdTCPConnection.IOHandler` has been assigned a `TIdIOHandlerSocket` or descendant).

Just know that if a timeout does occur, you can't know exactly which data was actually transmitted to the peer, so recovery is usually impossible in most protocols.  All you can really do is just close the connection and reconnect.